# Arrays, subarrays and merging subarrays within an array

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, append, concatenation

I am trying to make a list with three-dimensional arrays (numpy) in it.

I have this script:

```
for a in range(0, (len(s[1]))):
    object_location = s[1][a]
    object.append(object_location)
```

(in which s[1] is one array of coordinates from a list of arrays s[x], like this:

s[1]:

```
array([[ 157.8,    7.7],
       [ 368.3,    5.9],
       [ 416.3,   13.9]
       ..)
```

The above for-loop creates the following:

```
[array([ 157.8,    7.7]), array([ 368.3,    5.9]), array([ 416.3,   13.9])]
```

I would like to add to this two-dimensional list of arrays a third dimension, as follows:

```
[array([ 157.8,    7.7], [122.7,    6.9], [67.4,    2.5]), array([ 368.3,    5.9], [296.2,    4.1], [62.3,    1.7]), array([ 416.3,   13.9],[542.9,    4.5], [64.2,    1.5])]
```

For every a, an object[a] is created in my first script. 
Using something like append or concatenate, I would like to add values of different x'es to this (so to create the above three-dimensional arrays in a list, but how to?  A simple append or concatenate doesn't work, because either (concatenate): arrays do not have same number of dimensions. For append, it loses the separation of the grouped twodimensional object_locations (so it would give something like array([120, 14, 15, 19]), [70, 80, 90, 100])

So far, I have created the following script:

```
for a in range(0, (len(s[1]))):
    object_location = s[1][a]
    object.append(object_location)

for x in sections:
    for a in range(0, (len(s[x]))-1):
        if x < (len(sections)):
            nearest_value = [s[x+1][spatial.KDTree(s[x+1]).query(s[x][a])[1]]]
            object[a].append(nearest_value)
```

Problem with this script is that it says for the last line that 'numpy.ndarray' object has not attribute 'append'.

EDIT:
After the first loop in my script, object gives:
[array([ 157.8,    7.7]), array([ 368.3,    5.9]), array([ 416.3,   13.9])...], so a list with arrays. To every individual array, I want to include the coordinate from the  s[x+1] section and loop that for all x'es I have.

SECOND EDIT:

After producing the following list of arrays:

```
for b in range(0,20):
     print(len(axon[b]))
     np.squeeze(axon[b])
```

I acquire a list like this:

```
3
array([array([ 157.8,    7.7]), [array([ 117.4,   17.9])],
   [array([ 363.3,    6.1])]], dtype=object)
3
array([array([ 368.3,    5.9]), [array([ 364.8,    6.1])],
   [array([ 444.1,   13.4])]], dtype=object)
```

.. etc

On "np.concatenate" of this range, it still shows that my dimensions aren't the same, while it should be in this range, right? They are all arrays within arrays, which I want to convert to for example:

'correct array':

```
array([368.3, 5.9]), [364.8, 6.1], [444.1, 13.4])
```

Why is np.concatenate/np.asarray still not able to do this?

However, I have acquired the following by using () instead of [] in some places and by using extend for the values that are added to the array:

```
[array([ 368.3,    5.9]), 364.80000000000001, 6.0999999999999996,     444.10000000000002, 13.4]
```

While the values I want to append are in the following form, they are still added as arrays when I use 'append':

[ 117.4   17.9]
[ 364.8    6.1]

Is there a way to properly transform this to the 'correct array' above this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the `array()` notation? Is it for numpy?

Comment: yes! forgot to note that.

Comment: You can use `np.asarray(x)` to convert that list of arrays to a 2D array. But your problem still isn't clear...

Comment: I added my script to the question to clarify. Hope that helps! Now you see how x and a should work together.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to get the picture. One more question... in the first loop, what is `first_coordinate` and where does it come from?

Comment: Also, what is the initial value of `object` outside the first loop? (you should reconsider changing that name, it shadows the builtin class)

Comment: Sorry: first_coordinate IS object_location (overlooked that one). After the first loop, object is an array with subarrays for every [a].

Comment: Does this mean that there is no way to convert array([array([ 561. ,  312.5]), [array([ 547.4,  333. ])],
       [array([ 139.1,  318.5])]], dtype=object) into [array([561., 312.5], [547.4, 333], [139.1, 318.5])]? 

That seems difficult to grasp hihi

Comment: Think of it like this. You can represent a 2D array of [N, N] as a 1D array of size N * N. This is what numpy does. When you don't have equal number of rows, you can't convert to a 1D array because you'd have to take care of all the voids in the middle due to missing rows... and that can't be done if you convert it to a contiguous array, like you want.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. So would this mean that even creating the individual arrays in the first place is the wrong thing to do? I am really trying to get this proper list, which results in [array([ 157.8,    7.7], [122.7,    6.9], [67.4,    2.5]), array([ 368.3,    5.9], [296.2,    4.1], [62.3,    1.7])].

Comment: If you want it to be a list of list of lists, then don't even involve numpy. Your alternative is to, once you're done with your second loop, go through your array and see where there is a deficiency of rows and add 0's in their place. Not sure if that'd help your cause or not...

Comment: `np.squeeze` is not an inplace operation. Did you mean to assign it to something?

Comment: Another suggestion you could try is, extend everything so you have a 1D list of numbers. Then you can do `x = np.array(one_dim_list).reshape(-1, 2)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your extensive help and time. I finally managed to solve it with your suggestion of converting everything to a list first (tolist(), as simple as that) and then append. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad to know you got it. I'm sorry my original post did not help much. But hey, as long as it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clarifications, I believe this is what you want:

```
object.append([object_location])
```

First of all, I think you're a little confused between lists and arrays. They're similar, but a little different. In python, arrays are called lists. In numpy, they are arrays. What you're currently doing is simply inserting a bunch of 1D numpy arrays into a list, which looks somewhat like this:

```
[array([3, 3]), array([2, 3]), array([0, 1])]
```

Now, if you were to try to append something to, say element 0, you would get

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Because numpy arrays cannot be appended to the way lists can (they're fixed in size).

What you'd want, instead, is to have each array be put into another list, like this:

```
[[array([3, 3])], [array([2, 3])], [array([0, 1])]]
```

(Note the extra `[...]` around each array.

Now, when you try appending to, say, the 0th inner list, you'll get something like this:

```
[[array([3, 3]), array([4, 1])], [array([2, 3])], [array([0, 1])]]
```

Notice you've successfully appended another 1D array to the first one.

If all your inner lists have the same dimensions, you can then use `np.asarray(your_list)` to convert it to a 3D array (rather than a list of list of arrays):

```
[[[3 3]
  [4 1]]

 [[2 3]
  [3 4]]

 [[0 1]
  [2 0]]]
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying that...  So now I indeed yield multiple arrays within a given a in object[a] (like object[0] = [array([1, 1]), [array([1,3])], [array([3,2])]], but I need this to be something like [array([ 157.8,    7.7], [122.7,    6.9], [67.4,    2.5]). I reckon this is the last step in your description. I tried to fix that with:  for a in range(0, (len(s[x]))-1):
    np.asarray(axon[a]), but it didn't solve the issue. Did I think too simplistic? :)

Comment: Oh you were very quick to answer; still had to edit my comment! Yes I am familiar with the voting and accept system. :)

Comment: Yep... You will *not* be able to convert it to a pure 3D array as long as the number of rows in all the inner 2D arrays are not equal. I think this is what is happening, that your rows are not equal, so it is not getting converted as you'd like.

Comment: Hi! I tried to implement your method, but unfortunately it did not work out for me. Could you look at the edits?